# SQL - Next Twelve Months Average

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, datepart

I am trying to calculate Next Twelve Months Average.

I have calculated a Factor that depends on the Month that we want to look at:

```
365-DATEPART(dy,'2017-06-26')/365  & 1-365-DATEPART(dy,'2017-06-26')/365
```

I have been able to get the desired answer for one specified Date_Month yet I would like to be able to trim it down (remove nulls containing NULL) & make it possible to be applied to a multitude of Date_Months.

Here is the current Output:

```
Company_Id  Sales   Date_Year   Date_Month  NTMA_Factor Sales_Down  Sales_Up    NTMA_Sales
        1   675.051     2014    2013-03-31  0.7534      675.051     NULL        NULL
        2   47946.200   2014    2013-03-31  0.7534      47946.200   50364.200   48542.4788000
        2   50364.200   2015    2013-03-31  0.7534      50364.200   NULL        NULL
        3   6891.430    2014    2013-03-31  0.7534      6891.430    6917.450    6897.8465320
        3   6917.450    2015    2013-03-31  0.7534      6917.450    NULL        NULL
        5   2190.140    2014    2013-03-31  0.7534      2190.140    2318.250    2221.7319260
        5   2318.250    2015    2013-03-31  0.7534      2318.250    NULL        NULL
```

Is there a way to do this in SQL for a larger set of Date_Months?

Query so far:

```
SELECT top 7
    S.Company_Id
    , S.Sales
    , Y.Date_Year
    , M.Date_Month
    , N.NTMA_Factor
    , (S.Sales) AS Sales_Down
    , (LEAD(S.Sales, 1) OVER (Partition by S.Company_Id ORDER BY Y.Date_Year ASC)) AS Sales_Up
    , ((S.Sales * N.NTMA_Factor)  + (LEAD(S.Sales, 1) OVER (Partition by S.Company_Id ORDER BY Y.Date_Year ASC))*(1-NTMA_Factor)) As NTMA_Sales 
FROM Sales AS S
      INNER JOIN Date_Year AS Y ON Y.Date_Year_Id = S.Date_Year_Id
      INNER JOIN Date_Month AS M ON M.Date_Month_Id = S.Date_Month_Id
      INNER JOIN NTMA_Factor AS N ON N.Date_Month_Id = M.Date_Month_Id
where
    Date_Year in (2014,2015, 2013) and Date_Month in ('2013-03-31');
```

I would ideally want to have the exact same output but remove the Rows containing NULL & make it possible to look at more Date_Months (this means changing the Lead & Over statements so they just don't take the first one below as it seems to do now). I would also like to remove the Sales_Down & Sales_Up columns at the end but this does not seem to be a problem.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and new to Functions within SQL sadly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly (which isn't certain) you can use the [LEAD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) function with the [OVER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) clause, such as this:

```
SELECT
      S.Sales
    , Y.Date_Year
    , M.Date_Month
    , N.NTMA_Factor
    , (S.Sales * N.NTMA_Factor) AS NTMA_Sales_Down
    , LEAD(S.Sales, 1) OVER (ORDER BY Y.Date_Year ASC) AS SalesNextYear
FROM Sales AS S
      INNER JOIN Date_Year AS Y ON Y.Date_Year_Id = S.Date_Year_Id
      INNER JOIN Date_Month AS M ON M.Date_Month_Id = S.Date_Month_Id
      INNER JOIN NTMA_Factor AS N ON N.Date_Month_Id = M.Date_Month_Id
;
```

The LEAD and LAG functions allow you to "look forward" (lead) or "look backward" (lag) across rows, and I think this is the feature you are seeking. It is the OVER clause which supplies "controls" over how the functions operate. In this case there is a need to order by the year number.

*nb: There are a range of very useful "analytic" functions that also need or can use an over clause.  SUM() OVER() for example can provide a running total, or ROW_NUMBER() OVER() is exceptionally useful for returning first/last/earliest/latest rows*

Comment: Thank you, I have incorporated the code with a where clause and it seems to yield what I want for an individual company, do you know how to make this generalised so it applies the same output for a multituted of Date_Years & Date_Months instead of just taking the value from the row beneath it? (In the output there are a lot of Date_Year = 2014 hence this does not work because the code takes the wrong row as input for Sales in next year)

Comment: sorry, we crossed-over comments. To "generalize" I suspect you need to use the **PARTITION BY company** refer to the documentation links I provided. When used the LEAD/LAG will "recommence" for each new value in the "partition" you define. try it.